# Why cannot new Spring Boot Starter Project with in STS by “http(s)://start.spring.io” (error: Time out )?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, proxy

Please forgive me if I missed any common sense. I am new to Spring Boot & Maven, using Spring Tool Suite (version 3.9.3).RELEASE with Maven (3.2.5) and Java (version 1.8.0_201) for work. I use company proxy and network as well.

I tried to new a Spring Maven project using New `Spring Starter Project`. I tried to use urls http://start.spring.io and https://start.spring.io, but both failed with error **"SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"** and **No content available**.

[image: Check Error Message Picture]

Who can tell me what's the reason and how to solve? I noticed potential answers include "proxy issue", network connection issue, company firewall issue. But after I configured proxy with company proxy in settings.xml, the error is still there.

BTW, for who are looking for substitute solutions, I made it by choosing "New Spring Legacy Project" using "Simple Spring Maven". 
You may also try Spring Initializr. 
But Spring Initializr does not work for me neither.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Were you able to confirm that your IDE successfully establishes connection to internet through proxy?

Comment: IDE is Spring Tool Suite (version 3.9.3.RELEASE). I will try to configure proxy for STS IDE again using my company configurations. Thanks.

Comment: This error typically corresponds to proxy error in most cases. Check if you have to configure proxy manual in your organization

Comment: Can you reach the website via a browser? Optionally, you can download a .zip of the project setup directly from start.spring.io and then unzip it into your source code folder. It's essentially how the IDE does it.

Comment: @Coder Got you. Thanks. I will figure the proxy settings with company.

Comment: @Kieveli I tried download the zip file from start.spring.io. But unfortunately it did not work neither. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your network settings of STS.
You can do that by navigation to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections
and choose 'Active Provider' according to your use case - native worked for me.